# C# Application publishing issues

Tags: c#, installation, clickonce

I have just created a Windows 7 Desktop Application that allows you to essentially record your screen. I have included all the resources. I am treating it like a "load from CD" type app, as it requires some files as resources. When executing the files to the folder I have made on my desktop, I obviously get the Application files folder, with the manifest and DEPLOY files in; along with the ClickOnce.exe launcher. I then also get the DVD/CD setup.exe file and another clickonce app.

**Which installer should I use? And why am I getting these errors? See Below:**

When clicking the `setup.exe`, I receive this error: http://pastebin.com/kgXSnMJY

When Clicking the `Clickonce app` I get a similar error: http://pastebin.com/1CCT1CKx

**What could my issue be?**

Comment: Come on, a minus to start is not a good welcome. Instead give a comment to support the new OP in making the question better.

Comment: Grazie FeliceM :) Vedo che sei da Firenze.

Comment: Looks like you have a fail in the structure? Two time "Application Files/RecScreen_1_0_0_6"? --> "Downloading file:///C:/Users/Chris/Desktop/Publish area/Application Files/RecScreen_1_0_0_6/Application Files/RecScreen_1_0_0_6/RecScreen.exe.manifest did not succeed"

Answer (score -1):

I managed to avert this, by compiling the files like a "release" inside of a debug. The issue was with the resources I was using, the .dll's did not seem to download correctly (at least I don't think so). Thanks for all the advice and help :)